# ¿Cómo combinar la investigación de dos campos de búsqueda?

Tags: excel, vba, buscador

Tengo una lista de personal y un formulario de usuario para buscar en esta lista con varios campos.

```
Matric Apellido Nombre Avión
12     Burrow   Irving F15     
42     Nelson   Howard A10
18     Krings   Jack   F18
```

¿Cómo combinar las búsquedas de los dos campos de investigación?

Por lo momento hicé dos campos de búsqueda competidores quien se estrellan cuando busco en el uno o el otro.

```
Option Compare Text

Private Sub name_reservist_Change() 'www.blog-excel.com/creer-un-champ-de-recherche-vba

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ListBox1.Clear 'Exemple 2 (ListBox)

    If name_reservist <> "" Then
        For ligne = 2 To 24
            If Cells(ligne, 4) Like "*" & name_reservist & "*" Then
                ListBox1.AddItem Cells(ligne, 3) & " " & Cells(ligne, 4)
            End If
        Next
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub surname_reservist_Change() 'www.blog-excel.com/creer-un-champ-de-recherche-vba

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ListBox1.Clear 

    If surname_reservist <> "" Then
        For ligne = 2 To 24
            If Cells(ligne, 3) Like "*" & surname_reservist & "*" Then
                ListBox1.AddItem Cells(ligne, 3) 
            End If
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

Es la primera vez que hago un buscador. Si tienen consejos de diseño de navegador estoy interesado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

que tal todo?

Revisando tu codigo veo que estas usando algo llamado "texbox1" para comparar , creo que esto es erroneo y deberias hacer las comparaciones con "surname_reservist" o "name_reservist" segun el evento , pero puede que no haya entendido del todo tu codigo

He hecho algunas modificaciones a tu codigo :

Como puedes ver los eventos ya no utilizan "texbox1" , sino el valor del textbox que los llama para comparar

```
Private Sub name_reservist_Change()
    ListBox1.Clear
    If name_reservist <> "" Then searchresults
End Sub
```

```
Private Sub surname_reservist_Change() 'www.blog-excel.com/creer-un-champ-de-recherche-vba
    ListBox1.Clear
    If surname_reservist <> "" Then searchresults
End Sub
```

Ademas los 2 eventos llaman a un procedimiento nuevo que he creado "searchresults" , que es el que se encarga del bucle de busqueda

```
Sub searchresults()
 For ligne = 2 To 24
            If Cells(ligne, 4) Like "*" & name_reservist & "*" And Cells(ligne, 3) Like "*" & surname_reservist & "*" Then
                ListBox1.AddItem Cells(ligne, 3) & " " & Cells(ligne, 4)
            End If
        Next
End Sub
```

Espero que resuelva tu problema 
Cualquier duda me dices 
Si necesitas mas ayuda con tu buscador lo podemos hablar

Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias, me parece una buena idea. Sin embargo, ¿qué hago si realmente tengo muchos campos de investigación como [aqui](https://justpaste.it/img/70ea01107bf07764c2dc73917ed650bb.png)?

Comment: hay varias tecnicas: ampliar la funcion de filtrado "searchresults" , usar el metodo "autofilter" , pasar el rango a un array y recorrerlo , pasar el rango a un recorset y hacer una sql .....

Comment: Pienso que ampliar la funcion de filtrado "searchresults" riesga no facilitar la lectura del codigo hasta que hay varios campos. Tus otras ideas parecen interesantes ...

Comment: si se corre ese riesgo  , es menos elegante que utilizar ottras tecnicas , pero a cambio tienes mas control de las condiciones y si organizas bien el codigo puede quedar bastante legible y comodo para depurar

Comment: Voy a probar con recordset. Parece que es SQL

Comment: si , es SQL contra un rango , creo que era muy rapido